# Issues while serving django admin and react application together

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-react

I have hosted React app to be served as default application on "/" and it works fine. But when I am trying to access admin panel, I am getting following error.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve
```

Please let me know how I can approach it.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see the code to be sure but since the 404 is Raised by:  django.views.static.serve
I will check that :

document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT

and similar for MEDIA_ROOT